# Migrate customers passwords with salt

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, password

I need to import customers from the other shop system (oxid e CE) to Magento 1.9.
The best result would be reusing their password, so the customers can log in with their existing data into the new shop.

As far as I know, oxid uses md5 hash plus salt for encryption.
Is it possible to use these both fields to generate a md5 hash that Magento can use?

If not possible, I would try to display a message on login attempt for the imported customers that they will receive a mail with a link to reset their password. What would be the best approach for this method?

I think something like to pre-dispatch the login event and to check if this customer is one of the imported and has not reset his password.

Comment: If you save password just in md5 ,magento will accept and customer can login into your site

Comment: Is there any way to combine the md5 hash and the salt to achieve this?

Comment: well i am not sure about that, your can check in core class for more details

Comment: ok will have a look. if i found something ill post that here

Answer (score 1):

If you tell us how OXID is hashing the passwords, we might help you.

Magentos passwords look like this:

```
$this->hash($salt . $password) . ':' . $salt
```

An example: `027dfe2d795846ea0687514b0338d464:zj` in newer Versions, the hash is longer. It is important to see, that there is no seperator between salt and password and salt comes first.

In CE `$this->hash()` is `md5()` in EE it is some sha function.

Long story short: If OXID is hashing the same way you can just import the passwords, if it doesn't have a look into https://github.com/ikonoshirt/pbkdf2. I implemented an more secure way for password storing with PBKDF2 and for this I implemented a migration path to check wether the password is stored the new or the old way, you can use the same technique.